# How to save value from datetime picker to the database?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, sql-server-2005, ruby-on-rails-3

i can't save the data that come from my datetime picker to my database. i'm using Sql Server 2005 database.

here's my code in my application.js

```
$(function() {
    var dates = $( "#checkin, #checkout" ).datetimepicker({
        dateFormat: 'mm/dd/yyyy hh:MM:ss TT',
        defaultDate: "+1w",
        changeMonth: false,
        numberOfMonths: 2,
        minDate: new Date(),
        onSelect: function( selectedDate ) {
            var option = this.id == "checkin" ? "minDate" : "maxDate",
                instance = $( this ).data( "datetimepicker" ),
                date = $.datetimepicker.parseDate(
                    instance.settings.dateFormat ||
                    $.datetimepicker._defaults.dateFormat,
                    selectedDate, instance.settings );
            dates.not( this ).datetimepicker( "option", option, date );
        }
    });
});
```

here's my controller:

```
def step2
    @cart = current_cart    

    checkin = params[:checkin]
    checkout = params[:checkout]
    @amenities = Amenity.available(checkin, checkout)

    session[:checkin] = checkin
    session[:checkout] = checkout
end
```

and here's my datepicker view:

```
<%= form_tag :action => 'step2' do %>
   <%= label_tag 'checkin', "From:" %>
   <%= text_field_tag :checkin, params[:checkin] %>
   <%= label_tag 'checkout', "To:" %>
   <%= text_field_tag :checkout, params[:checkout] %>
   <%= submit_tag 'Show Availability' %>
<% end %>
```

and here where i will start to insert to my database:

```
<%= form_for(@transaction, :validate => true) do |f| %>     
    <%= f.hidden_field :Transaction_Date, :value => Time.now %>
    <%= f.hidden_field :rsv_type, :value => "Online" %>
    <%= f.hidden_field :rsv_status, :value => "Pending" %>
    <%= f.hidden_field :checkin, session[:checkin] %>
    <%= f.hidden_field :checkout, session[:checkout] %>
    #...
<% end %>
```

need some help.. :(

Comment: Where is the code which would send the date to your server?

Answer (score 0):

so one thing that jumps out at me is that you've got the datepicker value inputs id'd as "transaction_checkin" and "transaction_checkout". Doesn't this imply that they'll be in your params as

{:transaction => { :checkin => ..., :checkout => ...}}

If I'm not mistaken that means you're trying to pull these values out of the params from the wrong place.

```
checkin = params[:transatcion][:checkin]
checkout = params[:transaction][:checkout]
```

Comment: oh im sorry, i forgot to edit it. the real one is this. i really can't figure out how will i convert the datetime string to actual datetime. :(   thanks.

Comment: try this: your_date_string.to_date

Answer (score 0):

You can use Date.parse(date_string) to convert date_string to date format. Or you can use Time.parse(datetime_string) which will parse the datetime string to Time object.

Comment: where should i that? in my controller or in my model? sorry. i am noob in rails.

Comment: Its a ruby method for the Time/Date class. So you can use in Model or Controller, its your wish.